# Is it possible to find some value of $k$ such that the following inequality hold?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra

I want to estimate some costs in my program, but I encountered the following problem.

> Consider the following inequality, 
>   $$\sum_{i=1}^{k} \frac{y_i^2}{x_i} \leq \frac{(\sum_{i=1}^{k}y_i)^2}{\sum_{i=1}^{k}x_i}$$
>   , where all the variables are positive intiger.
>
> Is it possible to find some value of $k$ to make this inequality true ?

Answer (score 1):

If the $x_i$s and $y_i$s are all positive, then the inequality holds for all $k$. This follows from the [Engel form of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/m/Algebra/BergstromInequality.shtml).